# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' on LoanSimulation Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to showing list view from TextFormField to other pages
but the result in log say like this

```
E/flutter ( 9872): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
E/flutter ( 9872): #0      LoanResult.simulator (package:fluttermysql/models/LoanSimulationModel.dart:62:35)
E/flutter ( 9872): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9872): #1      _LoanSimulationState.result (package:fluttermysql/view/LoanSimulation.dart:29:5)
E/flutter ( 9872): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9872):
```

here is my LoanSimulationModel

```
static Future<LoanResult> simulator({String periodtime, String interestpermonth, String loanamountrequest, String idUser, String url}) async  {
    var url = "http://192.168.0.23/Api/loansimulation.php?periodtime=" + periodtime + "&interestpermonth=" + interestpermonth + "&loanamountrequest=" +loanamountrequest;
    final response = await http.get(url,headers:{"Content-Type":
    "application/json"});
    var res = LoanResult.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    return res;
  }
```

and here is result async

```
void result() async {
    LoanResult loanResult;
    await LoanResult.simulator(
        periodtime: periodtime,
        interestpermonth: interestpermonth,
        loanamountrequest: loanamountrequest,
        url: BaseURL.kLoanSimulationUrl)
        .then((value) => loanResult = value);
    print(loanResult.Status);
    if (loanResult.Status == true) {
      Text(loanResult.message);
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Simulator.id);
    } else {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(loanResult.message),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      ));
    }
  }
```

here is example from React Native
[image]

how can i get this result with List? thank you

Comment: `jsonDecode(response.body)` is returning a `List`. **Probably** it's a list of dictionaries with a single element (you can make this sure by printing its content), but if that's the case, you can use `jsonDecode(response.body).single`.

Comment: nope. this data from array so its return Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Too many elements
E/flutter (19540): #0      List.single (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:343:5)

Comment: Have you tried to print what `response.body` is returning and analyze what element do you want from it? `jsonDecode(response.body)[0]` will work, but I'm not sure if that's what you're expecting.

Comment: The Result should be like this   "No": 0,
        "interest": "0.00",
        "balance": "10,000,000.00",
        "principal": "0.00",
        "Installment": "0.00",
        "Status": true

Comment: What is `response.body` returning?

Comment: the result should be String type cannot using int and double?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: This looks like a new error. Have you solved the original problem? What have you changed in the original code to give this new error? Can you tell me what is `response.body` returning? Can you add a `print(response.body)` after you get the response and look what it'll print? After you look what it printed, can you post the result here or update the question with the output?

Comment: here is the response.body = [{"No":0,"interest":"0.00","balance":"12,000,000.00","principal":"0.00","Installment":"0.00","Status":true},

Comment: but the problem is not showing in listview on other pages I/flutter (10457): Error FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (10457): <br />

Comment: @BlancChen can you post the code for `LoanResult.fromJson()`

Comment: factory LoanResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LoanResult(
    interest: json["interest"],
    balance: json["balance"],
    principal: json["principal"],
    Installment: json["Installment"],
    periodtime: json["periodtime"],
    interestpermonth: json["interestpermonth"],
    loanamountrequest: json["loanamountrequest"],
    Status: json["Status"],
    message: json["message"]
  );

Comment: can you share your LoanResult model? and also share full API url so i can test in my postman

Comment: class LoanModel{
  LoanModel({
    this.No,
    this.interest,
    this.balance,
    this.principal,
    this.Installment,

  });
  String No;
  String interest;
  String balance;
  String principal;
  String Installment;
}